# how to write blank lines in object ADODB.Stream?

Tags: stream, adodb, filesystemobject

I want to know how to skip a/multiple line(s) in object `ADODB.Stream` in visual basic code. The only paramater for writing text that I know is `stream.WriteText` for this object. Parameter: 
`Write`, `WriteLine` and `WriteBlankLines` is for object `FileSystemObject`. So there is no way to type `stream.WriteBlankLines` under `ADODB.Stream`. It will pop-out error. If anyone knows, I appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 4):

Error is caused by `stream.vbcrlf`, using:

```
stream.WriteText vbCrLf
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the answer. Just type `stream.vbCrLf` after `stream.WriteText`. And it will go down and start at new line.